# What is the difference between function and feature

Tags: difference, usage

Is there a confusion between function and feature in the context of English usage?

Comment: f(x)=y, this is a function. How it can be confused with feature?

Comment: You should be more specific. "in the context of English usage" is too broad and useless, and it actually hurts your chances to get a proper answer. You probably mean "in English, in the context of describing requirements / systems".

Answer (score 1):

Functions can refer to a lot of things. There might be confusion if we are talking about functions and features in the context of products/marketing/technology.

> **Functions** describe what something does. It is goal based. It refers to what something does or is useful for.

For example, one function of that smartphone is that it can be used to browse the internet.

> **Features** are the tools that accomplish functions. It refers to characteristics or specifications.

For example, one feature of that smartphone is support for WiFi 5.